# Cannot enroll smartcard login

Tags: windows, smartcard

I've been tasked with attempting to set up smart cards for login in a test environment, however I'm encountering a very nasty problem.

Upon trying to load a certificate on a factory-new smart card through MMC's Certificate Enrollment, I'm getting the following error:

> A smart card was detected but is not the one required for the current operation. The smart card you are using may be missing required driver software or a required certificate.

I am using the `Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider` CSP built into Windows. I am following the steps explained in [this document](https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/hid_crescendoc1150_administration_guide_1_0.pdf) (differing card, but same method), specifically section 4.2.2.

The Smartcard is (correctly) being identified as an `Gemalto Cyberflex Access 64K V2c`. I have installed the ActivIdentity Mini Driver, which is registered in the Registry. The ATR listed in the Registry is correct, so I'm not sure what could be causing this error. My Enterprise CA is in my local Certificate Store, so I'm unsure what couldbe causing this issue.

What can I do to attempt to resolve this problem?

---

**Edit:** Upon attempting to change my card's PIN, I'm getting a related (?) error message:

> The card supplied requires drivers that are not present on this system. Please try another card.

This suggests drivers are to blame, but both the reader and the smartcard have the correct drivers installed.

**Edit 2:** `certutil -scinfo` generates this output, showing the card is being identified properly:

```
The Microsoft Smart Card Resource Manager is running.
Current reader/card status:
Readers: 1
  0: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0
--- Reader: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0
--- Status: SCARD_STATE_PRESENT
--- Status: The card is available for use.
---   Card: ActivIdentity Mini Driver (Gemalto Cyberflex Access 64K V2c)
---    ATR:
        3b 95 95 40 ff ae 01 03  00 00                     ;..@......


=======================================================
Analyzing card in reader: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0

--------------===========================--------------
================ Certificate 0 ================
--- Reader: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0
---   Card: ActivIdentity Mini Driver (Gemalto Cyberflex Access 64K V2c)
Provider = Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider
Key Container = (null) [Default Container]

Cannot open the AT_SIGNATURE key for reader: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0
Cannot open the AT_KEYEXCHANGE key for reader: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0

--------------===========================--------------
================ Certificate 0 ================
--- Reader: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0
---   Card: ActivIdentity Mini Driver (Gemalto Cyberflex Access 64K V2c)
Provider = Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider
Key Container = (null) [Default Container]

Cannot open the  key for reader: OMNIKEY CardMan 3x21 0

--------------===========================--------------

Done.
CertUtil: -SCInfo command completed successfully.
```

Comment: You have added the CA that signed the certificate that is stored on the card into the machine's Certificate Store?

Comment: @Ramhound There is no certificate stored on the card as far as I'm aware. The card is reporting itself as empty. This is happening during initial registration.

Comment: If it does not have a certificate store on it, then what do you have stored on the card, if it has no certificate how can it be used to identify a user?  I am deeply confused.  **I use a smart card daily to authenticate on my machine.**

Comment: @Ramhound The card is empty right now. I'm trying to add a certificate to it so I can use it to authenticate users.

Comment: So what is failing is your attempts to load the certificate on the card?  You still didn't answer my question about the CA though.

Comment: @Ramhound I have an Enterprise CA which is used to sign certificates. This is in the machine's Certificate Store and definitely works as intended. I'm trying to load a certificate onto factory-new cards, and I am getting the error mentioned in the post.

Comment: Alright;  Your question and problem is clear now,

Comment: The issue is either a problem with your certificate.  If this was being done programmatically by you, it would be likely connected to the declared container, take appropriate actions to verify the certificate is valid.  [Smart Card Minidriver Certification Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn390909.aspx)

Comment: Do you have a card that is loaded?  Have you verified the device's driver is being loaded when you log into your profile?

Comment: @Ramhound I have no loaded cards at all, unfortunately. The card reader and the card's driver are both present in Device Manager, so I assume that they are loaded.

Comment: @KazWolfe were you ever able to solve this?